# Element doesn't add to list .NET Core

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I have a stressful issue, I cannot add an element to a list, the operation doesn't throw any exception or anything, the element just doesn't get added.

The structure is as following.

I have class which I'm using as an in memory db. inside that class I have a list of objects with some default values.

The object type is an Author with the following structure

```
public class Author 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The list structure is like this

```
public class InMemoryStore
{
     public List<Author> Authors => new List<Author>
     {
            new Author(new Guid("5784f8b7-31b5-4886-8874-aff5241164a8"), "test"),
     } 
}
```

I'm registring the class as Scoped service and injecting it in my test controller the just do an Add, it results in nothing. It does not add the item
it does not throw any exception. I'm confused.

```
    private readonly InMemoryStore _inMemoryStore;
    public AuthorsController(InMemoryStore inMemoryStore)
    {
        _inMemoryStore = inMemoryStore;
    }
```

in Action

```
   _inMemoryStore.Authors.Add(author);
```

Creating same list inside the action, works

Comment: Do you understand what `Authors => ...` means? (Just to figure out how deep explanation should be)

Comment: @boris A new list is created each time you invoke the property getter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
public List<Author> Authors { get; } = new List<Author>
{
    new Author(new Guid("5784f8b7-31b5-4886-8874-aff5241164a8"), "test"),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Authors property is essentially a function that creates the list and returns it. 
It essentially is the same as this:

```
    public List<Author> Authors()
    { 
       return new List<Author>() 
       {
           new Author(new Guid("5784f8b7-31b5-4886-8874-aff5241164a8"), "test")
       }
    }
```

I think that you actually wanted to do this:

```
     public List<Author> Authors { get; set;} = new List<Author>()
     {
            new Author(new Guid("5784f8b7-31b5-4886-8874-aff5241164a8"), "test"),
     }
```

In this case Authors property is initialized to the default value with one author. You can add to that list later.

Comment: Note quite - the original `Authors` is a property, not a method.

Comment: I know that it is property but I noticed that OP does not know what => does exactly so he basically just wrote a function returning the list every time. It looked like property but worked like a function.

Comment: Ah but a property getter is a function: `get { return new List<Author>()`...

Comment: You are right again. Property is a function sprinkled with syntactic sugar.